# call a feature with a parameter in karate

Tags: karate

I read a lot of documentation, but i can figure out how to create a feature with a parameter.
I have a form with some textboxes and the only important one is the "name" input. I want to create a function/feature to fill those inputs and pass the value of the "name" trough a parameter

Something like:

```
 function textInputName(String name)  {
   name_locator = name
   }
```

and then call

```
textInputName("Peter")
```

I tried this :

Feature: createForm

```
  Scenario:
    And input(formNameTextBoxLocator,  { title: '#(name)'})
```

And then call it like this :

```
 call read('classpath:/WEB/Forms/createForm.feature') { name:"Peter" }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to solve it myself :)

First feature

```
@ignore
Feature: createForm
  * def Title = '#Title'
  Scenario:
    And input(formNameTextBox,  Title)
```

Second feature

```
* def formName = "Test form " + today
* call read('classpath:/WEB/Forms/createForm.feature'){ Title : #(formName)}
```

Comment: you can mark this answer as `accepted` now, it helps others